# Is it possible to generate Java Class from xsd or xml or json using apache camel

Tags: json, dynamic, xsd, apache-camel, pojo

My requirement is such that i want to generate Java Pojo java Class from the files such as xsd or xml or json kept in specific folder (which can be used as route for camel router ) .
Is this requirement possible using apache camel -spring boot?

I have read documents , and only found out about creating java object rather than java classes.

Please note : I want to create java pojo class and not java objects. I want to generate .java file

Comment: I am confused. You can easily generate Java classes from XSDs. But why would you want to generate Java classes from XML or JSON? Maybe some examples would help?

Comment: from which tool we can convert to pojo so that we can directly use it in TikXML library android.